# How to find an average for a Spark RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have read that reduce function must be commutative and associative. How should I write a function to find the average so it conforms with this requirement? If I apply the following function to count an average for an RDD it will not count the average correctly. Could anyone explain what is wrong with my function?

I guess that it takes two elements say 1, 2 and applies the function to them like `(1+2)/2`. Then sums up the result with the next element, 3 and divides it by 2 etc.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)

rdd.reduce((_ + _) / 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `PairRDD` to keep track of sum of all elements together with counts of elements.

```
val pair = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
.map(x => (x, 1))
.reduce((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

val mean = pair._1 / pair._2
```

Answer (score 3):

> rdd.reduce((_ + _) / 2)

There are a few issues with the above `reduce` method for average calculation:

1. The `placeholder` syntax won't work as the shorthand for `reduce((acc, x) => (acc + x) / 2)`
2. Since your RDD is of type integer, `rdd.reduce((acc, x) => (acc + x) / 2)` will result in an `integer division` in each iteration (certainly incorrect for calculating average)
3. The `reduce` method will not produce the average of the list.  For example:

   ```
   List[Double](1, 2, 3).reduce((a, x) => (a + x) / 2)
   --> (1.0 + 2.0) / 2 = 1.5
   --> (1.5 + 3.0) / 2 = 2.25
   Result: 2.25
   ```

   whereas:

   ```
   Average of List[Double](1, 2, 3) = 2.0
   ```

> How should I write a [reduce] function to find the average so it conforms with this requirement?

I'm not sure `reduce` is suitable for directly calculating the average of a list.  You can certainly use `reduce(_ + _)` to sum the list then divide the sum by its size, like:

```
rdd.reduce(_ + _) / rdd.count.toDouble
```

But then you can simply use RDD's built-in function `mean`:

```
rdd.mean
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

val lt =  sc.parallelize((List(2,4,5,7,2)))

lt.sum/lt.count